# Chart.js horizontal lines each draw a bit darker

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas, ionic2, chart.js

So I implemented some horizontal lines in my Chart like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mn8x6fso/27/

The Chart is inside a popup which is displayed when a Button is clicked.
Normally, the storkes should be I a light grey. But with each closing and creating of the Chart, the strokes are getting a bit dark, until they are solid black.

I tried things like `this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);` or to replace the canvas element with a new fresh one.
Nothing helped for me.

Has someone faced the same problem or does anyone have got a solution?